# Trying to delete records from a table that exist in another table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-delete

I am trying to delete records from table ersr2 that exist in table ersr but I get a syntax error.

Here is my command:

```
MariaDB> delete from ersr2 e2 where e2.child_id in (select e.child_id from ersr e);
```

But I get the following syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'e2 where e2.child_id in (select e.child_id from ersr e)' at line 1
```

I find this strange because the following command worked:

```
MariaDB> select e2.* from ersr2 e2 where e2.child_id in (select e.child_id from ersr e)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the alias: `delete from ersr2 where child_id in (select e.child_id from ersr e);`

Comment: or, use this form of the DELETE statement:  `delete e2.* from ersr2 e2 where ...`  (this is the form I generally use, because  I usually test the statement as a SELECT statement first, return the rows that I am going to delete. so I can review before accidentally deleting rows I didn't mean to delete.  I can also save off the results as a backup.  then changing `select e2.* from ersr2 e2 where` to a delete is a simple matter of replacing a single keyword

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the table for delete in delete clause  (delete e2)

```
delete  e2
from ersr2 e2
INNER JOIN  ersr e ON e.child_id = e2.child_id
```

and you could use inner join instead of a IN (sud query) clause